# How to extend FormGroup correctly

Tags: typescript, metadata, angular-forms, angular5

I'm currently trying to extend the FormGroup type of Angular5 to implement a custom method to receive modelstate errors and display them into another custom component.

Unfortunately, I've been receiving a not so informative error:

`Error: ServerValidatedForm/src/platform/svalidated/group.component.ts:30:1: Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol 'SVFormGroup':
ServerValidatedForm/src/platform/svalidated/group.component.ts:33:22: Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Expression form not supported.`

I'm suspecting that there's something that I miss on TypeScripting itself. Its good to notice that I've already cleaned up node_modules, removed all metadata from project and transpiled again and, every time I hit the same error.

I'm using:
`"@angular/animations": "5.0.1",
 "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
 "@angular/common": "5.0.1",
 "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.1",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.1",
 "@angular/core": "5.0.1",
 "@angular/forms": "^5.0.1"`

The important code is here, and ANY help will be of assitance: 
 
   `import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
 import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
 import { AbstractControlOptions } from "@angular/forms/src/model";`

```
@Injectable()
export class SVFormGroup extends FormGroup {
  constructor(
    controls: {[key: string]: any},
    validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn|ValidatorFn[]|AbstractControlOptions|null,
    asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn|AsyncValidatorFn[]|null) {
      super(controls, validatorOrOpts, asyncValidator);  
    }

setFromModelState(response: any, form: SVFormGroup) {
if(response.error && response.error.ModelState){
  let validationErrorDictionary = response.error.ModelState;
  for (var fieldName in validationErrorDictionary) {
    if (validationErrorDictionary.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
      if (form.controls[fieldName]) {
        form.controls[fieldName].setErrors(validationErrorDictionary[fieldName]);
      } else {                          
        this.setErrors(Object.assign(this.errors, validationErrorDictionary[fieldName]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}
`

And the complete code can be found at: `https://github.com/eduelias/servervalidatedform`

Comment: It's simple: You're using forms 5.0.1 with core 4.1.0. Don't do that. Use the same version for all the modules of the framework. That said, I think you're abusing inheritance. That code doesn't need to be in a subclass.

Comment: This child class will do a lot more. The problem is that has been almost impossible to make it work. With the 5.0.1 (which I thank you a LOT, because I really missed it) the error changed to: 
Error: C:/Users/Eduardo/source/repos/LAB15.A5.ServerValidatedForm/src/platform/svalidated/group.component.ts:30:1: Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol 'SVFormGroup':
 C:/Users/Eduardo/source/repos/LAB15.A5.ServerValidatedForm/src/platform/svalidated/group.component.ts:33:22: Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Expression form not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the problem was that I was registering the services wrong. Instead of registering it on the App.module instead of App.components - inside providers. As soon as I changed it, the problem vanished.